Alternative methods to Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\sec x}$
This integral is from the 2010 MIT Integration Bee. My attempt is below.
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\sec x}$$
We can rewrite this as the following:
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x\cos x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\cos x}{2+\sin(2x)}dx$$
From here I attempt to calculate the definite integral.
$$\int\frac{2\cos x}{2+\sin(2x)}dx=\frac{\cos x+\sin x+\cos x-\sin x}{2+\sin(2x)}dx=\int\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{2+\sin(2x)}dx+\int\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{2+\sin(2x)}dx$$
After implementing the double angle formula and the substitutions $t=x-\cos x$ and $u=\sin x+\cos x$ for the left and right sides respectively we are left with:
$$\int\frac{dt}{3-t^2}+\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\left| \frac{\sqrt{3}+t}{\sqrt{3}-t} \right|+\arctan u+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\left| \frac{\sqrt{3}+\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{3}-\sin x+\cos x} \right|+\arctan(\sin x+\cos x)+C$$
Now we evaluate all of that from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and after some tedious computation:
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ln(2+\sqrt{3})$$
I want to learn other solutions that are not so computationally intensive. There is a lot of room to make errors in the attempt I made.

Are you sure $t=x-\cos(x)$?

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\cos x+\sec x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x\cos x}dx\
=\frac12 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{1+\sin x\cos x}dx
=\frac12 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d(\sin x-\cos x)}{1+\frac12[1-(\sin x-\cos x)^2]}
$$

Why did you have $dx$ written twice?

It is much quicker and less painful if you use the King Property.
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\sec x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x\cos x}dx$$
After substitutions, we arrive at a much more manageable computation:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left[ \ln\left| \frac{\sqrt{3}+t}{\sqrt{3}-t} \right| \right]^1_{-1}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ln(2+\sqrt{3})}$$

If,a you did, you use the tangent half-angle substitution
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{2-2 t^2}{t^4-2 t^3+2 t^2+2 t+1}\,dt$$
$$t^4-2 t^3+2 t^2+2 t+1=
$$ $$\big(t^2+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)
   t+\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\big)\big(t^2-\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)
   t+\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)\big)$$ Using partial frcation dcomposition, the integrate is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigg(\frac {t+1}{t^2+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)
   t+\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right) }- \frac {t+1}{t^2-\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)
   t+\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)  }\Bigg)$$ which are not very difficult each of them leading to a logarithm and an arctangent (as ususal).
Using the bounds, simplifying and using the logarithmic representation of $\cosh ^{-1}(t)$
$$I=\frac{\cosh ^{-1}(2)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dx}{\sin x+\sec x} = \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\cos x}{\frac12\sin(2x)+1} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt2 \int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^\tfrac\pi4 \frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos(2x)+2} \, dx & x\to x+\frac\pi4 \\
&= 2\sqrt2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi4 \frac{d(\sin x)}{3-2\sin^2x} & \rm symmetry \\
&= \frac2{\sqrt3} \operatorname{artanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac23}\sin \frac\pi4\right) = \boxed{\frac2{\sqrt3} \operatorname{artanh}\frac1{\sqrt3}}
\end{align*}$$

$$
I =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x \cos x+1} dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x \sin x+1} d x
$$
Averaging them yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x \sin x+1} d x \\&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d(\sin x-\cos x)}{3-(\sin x-\cos x)^2}\\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\left[\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+u}{\sqrt{3}-u}\right)\right]_{-1}^1, \quad \textrm{ where }u=\sin x-\cos x \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ln (2+\sqrt{3})
\end{aligned}
$$
